# What are some good ways to transfer data between two independent python programs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-transfer

I have two independent python modules running in the background on my device. Even though I need them to be independent, I need some string data transferred from one to the other every few seconds. I'm currently doing it by writing the data into a text file which is constantly being monitored by the two. Is there any better way to do it? Something faster, more secure if possible.

Comment: Are you appending data to the text file, or writing a new text file each time?

Comment: Hundreds of ways. How about a named pipe? Or use zeromq and let it figure it out.

Comment: If you keep appending to the file you end up archiving the data. That may be a nice feature.

Comment: I am overwriting a file each time.

Comment: Don't need archives in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is a **named pipe**, also known as **fifo**, which is a mechanism for **inter process communication**. According to `man-pages`: 
*"A FIFO special file (a named pipe) can be opened by
       multiple processes for reading or writing.  When processes are
       exchanging data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data internally
       without writing it to the filesystem.  Thus, the FIFO special file
       has no contents on the filesystem; the filesystem entry merely serves
       as a reference point so that processes can access the pipe using a
       name in the filesystem."*

This is a usage example of named pipes in `python`:

```
import os

NAMED_PIPE = 'mypipe'

try:
    os.mkfifo(NAMED_PIPE)
except OSError: 
    raise

with open(NAMED_PIPE) as fifo:
    while True:
        data = fifo.read()
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        print('[x] Data: {}'.format(data))
```

Comment: Thanks. Had never known this before. This is exactly what I'd needed.